# Is it possible to segregate components of verbal and visuospatial working memory using n-back paradigm?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, working-memory, neuropsychology

I am trying to segregate different components of verbal working memory and visuospatial working memory.

In order to assess verbal working memory I am using an auditory version of n-back task with a load levels ranging from 1 to 2. The task requires the participant to respond when they here the same consonant one after the other (1-back condition) or when they hear the same consonant at an interval of another consonant (2-back condition)

In order to assess visuopatial working memory I am using a spatial n-back task. The memory load ranges from 1 to 2.  A set of cards are shown to the subjects sequentially, each card has a small back color dot on a white background. The position of the dot changes from card-to-card. The subject has to respond when they saw the dot appearing on the same location in comparison to the previous card (1-back condition) or after an interval of one card (2-back condition).

I am not sure whether it can segregate the components of verbal and visuospatial working memory.

Is there an article that might give me a clue as what component is tapped in the 1 n-back load level and 2 n-back load level?

Thanks
Vatsal